# How to validate the inputs from user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, postman

I want to invalidate some inputs.I write these code in `store` method,but when I test my `api` on `Postman` give me `500` error.For example I don't give `body`field in `Body` tab.
This is `store` function in my controller.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validation=$this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(),[
        'body'=>'required',
        'image'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,png'
    ]);
    if($validation->failed()){
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Invalid Input Data!'],400);
    }
    $article=new Article();
    $article->title=$request->title;
    $article->body=$request->body;
    $article->source=$request->source;
    if($article->save()){
        $article->categories()->sync($request->categories);
    }
    $name='article-'.$article->id.'.'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->file('image')->move(public_path('images'),$name);
    $article->image= $name;
    $article->save();
    return response()->json(['message'=>'save successfully'],200);
}
```

This is migration file for create `article` table.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
        $table->enum('status',['draft','completed','published'])->default('draft');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And this is `Postman` screenshot.
[image: Output Postman]

Comment: you have error on this line `if($article->save())`

Comment: What is the error? If validation be failed, must return and program don't go to this line.

Comment: 500 must be an exception. You can check the storage/logs/laravel-2018-10-08.log to see the error message, or post it.

Comment: The log may be useful. It's also helpful to use the data dump function in Laravel at different points along the way. Try data dumping the request right at the beginning of the function to make sure that you are passing the data correctly and haven't made a mistake. If everything is ok, try data dumping $validation right after you call the validation request and before you check if it's failed to see what the actual response is. If there is a 500 error before this, then you are probably doing something wrong on the routing or front end.

Comment: @eResourcesInc: Passing data is correct.I try data dumping $validation and I receive many line html code and in JSon mode : `Unexpected '<' `